# Good picture seforim (books) for nach

Tags: jewish-books, tanach

I am having a hard time keeping track of all of the places and wars in Sefer Yehoshua and Shoftim (and probably will for the rest of nach). Are there any good seforim which go through nach and have pictures of the events like the wars, travels or things pertaining to the splitting of land, etc.? I have access to the full otzar hachochma, so being out of print is not a problem. I have breifly seen the Da'at Mikra Bible Atlas, and may use it, but might need something with more pictures about the pesukim themselves and more clearly following along with the pesukim.

Comment: For Yermiyahu and for megilas esther ,Rav Landy's books

Comment: For calculations of dates and the more central genealogies, there's Eliezer Shulman's סדר הקורות בתנ"ך in Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew [Artscroll Mikraos Gedolos](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/HMG.html) nach series has very nice color maps, travel, and the splitting of Eretz Ysroel.And as you have mentioned the Da'at Mikra Bible Atlas is also very good.

As @sam pointed out that [Rav Landys](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/search.asp?advs=1&author=Rabbi%20Yehuda%20Landy) books are excellent.